# Devise ensure_authentication_token reports undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

User model looks sth like this:

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  :token_authenticatable

attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, 
                :cell_phone, :city, :state, :country, :user_type
```

In devise.rb file I have uncommented:

```
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```

My user migration looks like:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   create_table(:users) do |t|
    t.database_authenticatable :null => false
    t.recoverable
    t.rememberable
    t.trackable
    t.token_authenticatable
    t.timestamps
   end

   add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
   add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
   add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
   drop_table :users
  end
end
```

While creating a user, following parameters comes

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"+F8cjCoauVKhZPSJLhW+AAhui1DygBcODsYn4Va/ktY=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"any_name",
 "last_name"=>"any_name",
 "email"=>"any_email@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "cell_phone"=>"any_number",
 "city"=>"some_city",
 "state"=>"some_state",
 "country"=>"U.S.A",
 "user_type"=>"student"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

But still I get following error while creating user:

```
NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

   undefined local variable or method `ensure_authentication_token' for #<User:0x007fd4448f7350>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

P.S. In my Gemfile, Devise gem is configured as follows:

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Comment: Why is the line `before_save :ensure_authentication_token` in the model ? What is the rationale?

Comment: According to resources I found it should be in user class. So I have kept in the model.

Comment: What resources? I belive that's the culprit, if you remove it the error will go away, but the question is "what are the implications?".

Comment: I want to be able to save token_key in the authentication_token field of User model. For that I'll have use this callback. This is the conventional way to do even this has been mentioned in the book I read call "Rails 3 in Action" published by Manning. Btw if I remove that the error will obviously will go away but with job undone. 

You can see here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb , what this callback does.

Comment: I understand now. Very strange indeed. Try in the console `User.new.methods.grep /ensure_authentication_token/` to see if the method is indeed there.

Comment: it returns a blank array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry it was my bad, I missed a comma :)

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, #here
  :token_authenticatable
```

Its working now.

Comment: LoL. Same exact problem I ran into. Thanks so much.

Comment: Lol! I know, sometimes you get stuck with small things like this and you can't get proper information about the bug in backtrace. I wish the backtrace was more user friendly and smarter. But anyways, I'm glad you found the glitch. ;)

Comment: I just cannot believe it the very same just happened to me.